# Salesforce Classic to lightning migration

Tags: lightning

Im working on SFDC classic org which has been asked to be migrated to Lightning.
Im not able to figure out how to replace the java script validation button.
I have Convert button on lead object which has onclick java script to validate if few of fields are not empty, if empty shows error message. What provision is there in lightning to accomplish this?

Comment: The topic is too broad to answer. If you edit your question and where exactly problem arises for you, community would answer. The best place to start is :- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/lex_admin_migration and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_transition_assistant.htm&type=5

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be login to https://lightning-configuration.salesforce.com/ using your org credential and scan for JavaScript button and convert it to Lightning Component, quick actions, or other declarative solutions.

[image]

Read more here:- [Convert JavaScript Buttons to Lightning-Friendly Alternatives with the Lightning Experience Configuration Converter](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/convert-javascript-buttons-to-lightning-friendly-alternatives-with-the-lightning-experience-configuration-converter.html)

> Remember:- The above tool can’t convert every JavaScript button.

Also,

[Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration) would discover Lightning-friendly solutions for your JavaScript button use cases.

Comment: I'm not able to see a list of  visual force pages with issues in it... after scanning org in Lightning Experience configuration converter. Also button for apply lightning stylsheet is disabled

Comment: You can open a separate question for this query so that in future other people can take advantage of it.